# Node JS, Promise.all() checking null?

Tags: node.js

My code looks like below

```
Promise.all()....

//if previous promise is fulfilled, then it runs (if it`s not undefineded)
Promise.all()....

//if previous promise is fulfilled, then it runs (if it`s not undefineded)
Promise.all()....
```

The problem is that I want to check that the return value of the previous promise is not null or [undefined] rather than fulfilled. What's the way?

Comment: Can you please explain more.

Comment: `Promise.all` can never return `null` or `undefined`, it always returns an array ... If you, on the othre hand want to check wheter one of the promises you pass to `Promise.all` returns `null` or `undefined` before you call the next `Promise.all` you would either need to `await` the prior `Promise.all` or only call the next `Promise.all` in the `then()` handler of the prior one ...

Comment: @derpirscher yah Promise.all return array but Let's assume that the job was not handled well on another server. In this case, nesting with catch makes the code too dirty,(And there may be abnormal terminations that are not caught by the catch error on another server.) so I just want to separate it and check whether it received a value properly or not.

Comment: If you want to check whether one (or more) of the promises you passed to `Promise.all` rejected, use `Promise.allSettled` instead of `Promise.all` like suggested by Terry Lennox ...

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array of the operations to be run like `[op1, op2, op3]`.

You could then run through this list and use [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) to get the result of each operation as as a list like:

```
[
  {status: "fulfilled", value: 10},
  {status: "rejected",  value: 20},
]
```

For each step, if any status is "rejected", we log and return.

```js
// Generate a promise with 10% chance of rejection...
function generatePromise() {
    let success = Math.random() < 0.90;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(success ? resolve: reject, 100, success ? Math.floor(Math.random() * 100): new Error('Some error')));
}

function op1() {
    return [generatePromise(), generatePromise()]
}

function op2() {
    return [generatePromise(), generatePromise()]
}

function op3() {
    return [generatePromise(), generatePromise()]
}

async function runOperations(operationArr) {

    for(let idx = 0; idx < operationArr.length; idx++) {
        console.log(`Running operation ${operationArr[idx].name} (${idx + 1} of ${operationArr.length})...`)
        let result = await runOperation(operationArr[idx]);
        if (!result) {
            console.log(`Operation ${idx + 1} failed, returning...`);
            return;
        }
    }
    console.log('All operations successful!')
    return true;
}

async function runOperation(op) {
    let results = await Promise.allSettled(op());
    return !(results.find(({ status, value }) => status === 'rejected'));
}

let operationsToBeRun = [ op1, op2, op3 ];
runOperations(operationsToBeRun);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

If Promise.allSettled is not available, you can get the same result using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), wrapping in a runOperation() method:

```js
// Generate a promise with 10% chance of rejection...
function generatePromise() {
    let success = Math.random() < 0.90;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(success ? resolve: reject, 100, success ? Math.floor(Math.random() * 100): new Error('Some error')));
}

function op1() {
    return [generatePromise(), generatePromise()]
}

function op2() {
    return [generatePromise(), generatePromise()]
}

function op3() {
    return [generatePromise(), generatePromise()]
}

async function runOperations(operationArr) {

    for(let idx = 0; idx < operationArr.length; idx++) {
        console.log(`Running operation ${operationArr[idx].name} (${idx + 1} of ${operationArr.length})...`)
        let result = await runOperation(operationArr[idx]);
        if (!result) {
            console.log(`Operation ${idx + 1} failed, returning...`);
            return;
        }
    }
    console.log('All operations successful!')
    return true;
}

async function runOperation(op) {
    try {
        let results = await Promise.all(op());
        return true;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`An error occurred running ${op.name}:`, err.message);
        return false;
    }
}

let operationsToBeRun = [ op1, op2, op3 ];
runOperations(operationsToBeRun);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: I was trying to test but I can not auto complete allSettled() do you know why? it is because of node version?

Comment: Could be, it's available from Node.js 12.9.0 onwards. If Promise.allSettled is not available, it's possible to work around it...